# MuleSoft: Data Type Fragment: Append a data property to an !included datatype.raml file

Tags: types, mulesoft

In my case there's a basic datatype1.raml file containing the following properties:

```
properties:
  name: string
  email: string
  phone: string
```

Then another 2 data type fragment files: datatype2.raml & datatype3.raml both containing the following properties:

```
type: object
properties:
   company: string
   contactList: 
     type: array
     items:
       !include /datatype1.raml
```

The question is, how can I append the following property after the above '!include' line to include it in the items of the 'contactList' array in the datatype2.raml only?

```
id: integer
```

Note: The above is to have the "id" mandatory in the datatype2.raml (but not in the datatype3.raml) thus it produces the following result:

```
 contactList: 
   name: string
   email: string
   phone: string
   id: integer
```

Thanks,

Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `properties` to the type you define using the `!include`, same like you would do it when you are defining a new object

You can refer [this medium](https://medium.com/raml-api/using-raml-inheritance-to-design-better-schemas-9ce75155df7c) article for more info regarding inheriting datatypes.

In your case you can use it like the below

```yaml
type: object
properties:
   company: string
   contactList: 
     type: array
     items:
       type: !include /datatype1.raml 
       properties: 
         id: string
```

This will make the `!include /datatype1.raml` to add more properties that you define in your raml

Comment: Please add an example in the answer.